# Water softener standpipe question

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

I have a 1 1/2 inch standpipe coming off of a 2 inch drain pipe in my basement. The only thing before the stand pipe is the kitchen sink. And after the standpipe is a pipe coming down from the washing machine. But there is no p trap for the washer, only a running trap a few feet down the line from where the washer drain comes down.

But there is a wye with a service 45 going into a trap and an air gap on top for the water softener. 
Now the only problem I’m having is I notice some bubbles coming out of the air gap vent. Could it be that the washing machine is draining too fast for that in-line tubing trap to handle?

I have a quick little sketch since I’m having trouble getting a full picture of everything. It seems to work fine when the water softener is backwashing or anything else is draining.

Just wanted a second opinion.

[image]

Comment: You're saying that suds are getting past the softener standpipe trap? Are you using an appropriate amount of the appropriate detergent? Sequential traps like that aren't right, btw. I'd move the trap to the washer standpipe where it belongs.